# What are JUnit @Before and @Test

Tags: java, junit, annotations

What is the use of a Junit `@Before` and `@Test` annotations in java? How can I use them with netbeans?

Comment: PLEASE provide more information, otherwise we don't know what you want to know.

Comment: https://onlyfullstack.blogspot.com/2019/02/junit-tutorial.html

Answer (score 58):

Can you be more precise?
Do you need to understand what are `@Before` and `@Test` annotation?

`@Test` annotation is an annotation (since JUnit 4) that indicates the attached method is an unit test. That allows you to use any method name to have a test. For example:

```
@Test
public void doSomeTestOnAMethod() {
  // Your test goes here.
  ...
}
```

The `@Before` annotation indicates that the attached method will be run **before** any test in the class. It is mainly used to setup some objects needed by your tests:

*(edited to add imports) :*

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*; // Allows you to use directly assert methods, such as assertTrue(...), assertNull(...)

import org.junit.Test; // for @Test
import org.junit.Before; // for @Before

public class MyTest {

    private AnyObject anyObject;

    @Before
    public void initObjects() {
        anyObject = new AnyObject();
    }

    @Test
    public void aTestUsingAnyObject() {
        // Here, anyObject is not null...
        assertNotNull(anyObject);
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot..this is what i wanted to know..What packages do i add to use the @test and @ before annotations and how do i do it in netbeans?

Comment: As provided in romaintaz' answer: import org.junit.Test; // for @Test
import org.junit.Before; // for @Before

Comment: @romaintaz - Does the '@Before' method run before each of the tests in the file or does it run once for all the tests in the file?

Comment: @ziggy '@Before' is called before every test in the class. Use '@BeforeClass' on a static method to run the method only once, for ex. To initialize your tests context.

Comment: Is it before *any* test or before *each* test (as guerda says)? The documentation is unclear, but I suspect guerda has the right of it. Please update your answer if you have it wrong here.

Answer (score 22):

1. If I understood you correctly, you want to know, what the annotation [`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/org/junit/Before.html) means.
   The annotation marks a method as to be executed before *each* test will be executed. There you can implement the old `setup()` procedure.
2. The [`@Test`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc_40/org/junit/Test.html) annotation marks the following method as a JUnit test. The testrunner will identify every method annotated with `@Test` and executes it. Example:

   ```
   import org.junit.*;

   public class IntroductionTests {
       @Test
       public void testSum() {
         Assert.assertEquals(8, 6 + 2);
       }
   }
   ```
3. `How can i use it with Netbeans?` In Netbeans, a testrunner for JUnit tests is included. You can choose it in your Execute Dialog.

Comment: Hi am sorry i meant @ test annotation and how do i add the JUNIt package and use it in my netbeans project.