# java.lang.NullPointerException in appium

Tags: java

This is my appium java code, after starting the test its stopping in app login method and says java.lang.NullPointerException. I tried all my possible solutions, but its not at all working please help to solve this problem

```
public class FirstAutomate {
private WebDriver driver;

@Test

public void setup() throws Exception {


   File app = new File("C:\\sdk\\platform-tools\\Myapp.apk");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    //capabilities.setCapability("BROWSER_NAME", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("VERSION", "5.0.2"); 
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","G3 Beat");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.skooly.app");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.skooly.app.screens.prehomescreens.activities.SplashScreen");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");

    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
    try{
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }catch(MalformedURLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
 @Test

    public void AppLogin() throws InterruptedException {
    //Tapping  button
     driver.findElement(By.id("loginButtonTextView")).click();
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know appium, but I would not assume that `setup()` is called before your `AppLogin()` on the same instance of your test.

Comment: Try `@Before public void setup() throws Exception { ...` or something like that.

Comment: can you add the stack trace ?

Comment: What testing framework are you using to run your appium tests?

Comment: @JimmyB I'm using Junit, thanks it worked for me great :-)

Comment: @JimmyB After adding "@Before", AppLogin() works perfectly, but the button click happens in milliseconds, i cannot able to see the splash screen which contain the "Login" button. It is directly going to login screen. Implicitwait is also not working, also i doesn't know where i need to add implicit wait exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JUnit, each of your tests, annotated with `@Test`, is run *independently* from any other. That's why you cannot set up some data ("`driver`") in one `@Test` and expect it to be there in another `@Test`.

To do initialization work before each test, use the `@Before` annotation, as in

`@Before public void setup() throws Exception { ...`

This will make `setup()` run and set up your `driver` before every actual test, i.e. `AppLogin()` in your case. See for instance [JUnit before and test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531371/junit-before-and-test).