# Appium Java Client Version vs Selenium Version

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

Can any one please tell me how do I make sure which appium `java-client` jar version is compatible with which selenium jar version. I have tried a lot of different appium `java-client` versions and also selenium versions and I faced below issues :-

1. `org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement cannot be cast to io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement with java-client 4.1.2 ans selenium 3.9.1`
2. `java.lang.NullPointerException with java-client 4.1.0 ans selenium 3.9.1`
3. `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with java-client 6.0.0 ans selenium 3.13.0`
4. `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with java-client 6.0.0 ans selenium 3.9.1`

The list is long.

I have tried a lot of thing and finally it worked for me with `Java-client 2.1.0` and `selenium version 2.45.0`

These are old version and I want to work with newer once.
Is there a way to find out which java-client version works perfectly with which selenium version ?

Is there any link where there is a list of it or something instead of try all permutation and combination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the [Appium news](https://discuss.appium.io/c/news) section to get updates about the concerned dependency for selenium - java.

Example: 
To know about the Java - Client 5.0.2 release and to know about it's dependency visit the below link

[Java-client-5-0-2](https://discuss.appium.io/t/java-client-5-0-2-released/18439)

You will find the update like this

[image: Release update and changes]

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use the following versions :

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0-BETA5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Even I had faced such issues, after few permutations the above versions work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess for this is that You might be having issues with environment. If is not too much inconvenient for You, use latest drivers for both Selenium and Appium.

I wrote in Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379757/webelement-click-giving-java-lang-nullpointerexception-in-appium?noredirect=1#comment89802239_51379757) You can use for eg. this environment:

- [Appium java-client (6.1.0)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/6.1.0)
- [Appium server (1.6.2)](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.6.2)
- [Selenium java-client (3.13.0)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.13.0)

if You still have issues try with this appium tool, appium-doctor.

**Use appium-doctor to verify setting**

After installation, we can run appium-doctor to verify settings:

```
appium-doctor
```

The green check mark of all settings indicate us that we can start next chapter - execute the existing appium demos from its source.

You can also use the appium-doctor in the appium GUI tool to verify sesstings.

if You don't have it installed:

```
npm install appium-doctor -g
```

and then following commands to check your settings

**(android)**

```
appium-doctor -- android
```

**(ios)**

```
appium-doctor --ios
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I tried with java client 6.1.0 and selenium 3.13.0 and appium server 1.7.1 but it didn't work for me, it gave java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonOutput.write(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/json/JsonOutput; error. The server version is not an issue, its just the version matching between java-client and selenium.

Comment: But this error I don't see to have relations with version, they are compatible for sure, something else seems to be bothering You. Version are compatible. Start by debug step-by-step and try to pinpoint the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Before that Selenium Server was complaining about one Desired Capability:
waitForQuiescence. 
When I run the same tests against my local there was no problem with "waitForQuiscene"

Comment: This does not answer my question, besides it is already answered below. Although the solution you gave is quite good if you already know the version compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In the Maven-Repository you can see the necessary version of Selenium:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.1.0