# usage of @Before in Junit Testing

Tags: java, junit

`@Before` notation in JUnit Testing is needed because several tests need similar objects created before they can run.

But I don't get the difference between instantiating an object before the testcase function as a global object and putting inside a `@Before`.

For example, I am testing my chess program and I am testing if my Piece object moves to a correct place by doing :

```
public class PawnTest { //The Test Class itself

Board board = new Board();

@Test
/**
 * Testing the right movement
 */
public void correctMovementTest() {
    Pawn p1 = new Pawn(Player.UP);
    board.placePiece(4, 3, p1);
    board.movePieceTo(5, 3, p1);
    assertEquals(board.getPiece(5, 3), p1);
}

@Test
/**
 * Testing the right movement
 */
public void correctMovementTest2() {
    Pawn p1 = new Pawn(Player.UP);
    board.placePiece(4, 3, p1);
    board.movePieceTo(6, 3, p1);
    assertEquals(board.getPiece(6, 3), p1);
}

....
```

So wouldn't it just work if I decalre `Board` and `Pawn` `p1` outside the testcase method? Why would we need `@Before` in the test class?

Also, doing this won't work

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Board board = new Board();
    Pawn p1 = new Pawn(Player.UP);
}
```

I thought this would actually set up the objects before the test cases so that I won't have to set them up on every test cases, but the test cases wouldn't actually read the p1 object and the board.

Comment: P1 is a local variable. Make it a member variable. Read more about scopes of variables.

Comment: So, how would I have to set it up to prevent duplicated code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JUnit before and test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531371/junit-before-and-test)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`@Before`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html) annotation is used to do something before executing each test case in your class. So, basically you're on the right way. To make your code work, you need to declare your `Board` and `Pawn` outside of function scope.

```
Board board = null;
Pawn p1 = null;

@Before
public void setup() {
    board = new Board();
    p1 = new Pawn(Player.UP);
}
```

There is also [`@BeforeClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) annotation available to execute some actions once before executing entire test suite - for example start embedded database.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Technically , having instance fields ( declaration plus initialization both ) in your test class and having instances created in `@Before` method ( only references declared as instance fields ) are same thing i.e. your global data will become available to all of your `@Test` methods since JUnit automatically creates an instance of test class for each `@Test` method run so `@Before` is not **ALWAYS** needed.

But with Approach # 1 ( declaration plus initialization both as instance fields ) , you are unnecessary tying up your test class instance creation and test data preparation while keeping concerns separate and visualizing the process in terms of stages is a good idea like , **Create Instance of Test class -> Create Instance of SUT ( Service Under Test ) -> Prepare Test Data for SUT -> Call Test Method etc...** ( Just a sample ).

`@Before` approach was a necessity with usage of mocking frameworks too as mocks needed to be initialized first in `@Before` method but that doesn't seem a necessity anymore . [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494926/initialising-mock-objects-mockito)

You have to realize that example put forward by you is very simple while in enterprise applications , classes to be unit tested are very complicated and folks don't want to clutter their field declaration area with test data preparation.

All in all - `@Before` is not mandatory for a reason - i.e. you use it if you wish to do certain things after creation of test class instance ( if that use case really fits in your scenario ) otherwise you are free to prepare your test data as instance fields.

Answer (score 1):

`@Before` and `@BeforeClass` are useful to set up peripherals used by your tests. `@Before` will run before every test, while `@BeforeClass` will run before the test suite (eg once before all the tests.)

Lets say your tests all have some common setup that needs to be done before running. You *could* always just create some sort of utility method `setup` and then call it manually before every class:

```
private void setup() {
  // do stuff
}

@Test
public void testFoo() {
  setup();
  // do test
}

@Test
public void testBar() {
  setup();
  // do test
}
```

... Or you could just annotate the `setup` method with `@Before` and have JUnit do that for you:

```
@Before // JUnit will now call before every test, without you needing to do anything
public void setup() {
  // do stuff
}

@Test
public void testFoo() {
  // do test
}

@Test
public void testBar() {
  // do test
}
```

The `@BeforeClass` annotation works under a similar concept, except that it hooks before the entire suite and runs once.

Personally I find myself using these situations when I have to mock out dependencies.

Consider, for example, a class which has a dependency on a database connection. In my `@Before`, I'll create a mocked instance of this database connection that my tests can inject/use as needed:

```
private DbConnector mockDb;

@Before
public void initMocks() {
  mockDb = Mockito.mock(DbConnector.class);
}
```

If I don't mind my tests all sharing the same instance, I can make `mockDb` static and use `@BeforeClass`.

In your particular case, you have `Board` instance. If you want your tests to share the same Board -- eg there are no side effects to running different tests on a given board -- then you can create the new instance using `@BeforeClass`:

```
private static Board board;

@BeforeClass
public static void initBoard() {
  board = new Board();
  // other board init logic here
}
```

Maybe we want to share the same Board instance everywhere, but we need to do some cleanup or setup logic. Then we can annotate such methods with `@Before` and `@After` to run them around each test instance to put the board into the expected state.

```
@Before
public void setupBoard() {
  // setup logic, runs before each test (maybe puts the pieces where they should go for a new game?)
}

@After
public void resetBoard() {
  // reset logic, runs after every test (maybe remove scores, resets mocks, etc?)
}
```

When to use these annotations, and which specific ones to use really rely on how your tests are designed. If, for example, setting up your Board is simply just `new Board();` and nothing else, you don't really need the `@BeforeClass` method and you can just use a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example:

The method annotated `@Before` runs before each call to `@Test`

So what I would do to solve your problem is to convert the local variable a field. In that way, the variable is accessible to each test methods.

```
 public class PawnTest { //The Test Class itself

 Board board;
 private Pawn p1;
@Before
public void setup() {
    board = new Board();
    p1 = new Pawn(Player.UP);
}


@Test
/**
 * Testing the right movement
 */
public void correctMovementTest() {
    board.placePiece(4, 3, p1);
    board.movePieceTo(5, 3, p1);
    assertEquals(board.getPiece(5, 3), p1);
}

@Test
/**
 * Testing the right movement
 */
public void correctMovementTest2() {
    board.placePiece(4, 3, p1);
    board.movePieceTo(6, 3, p1);
    assertEquals(board.getPiece(6, 3), p1);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    p1 = null;
    board = null;
}
```

Added tear down so that the test cases are independent of each other.

EDIT: Moved `board` initialization to `setUp()`

Comment: While you're editing it, add some context to this code.  Code-dump answers are not useful to anyone.

Comment: The tests are now also dependent on each other because they share the same board. - ah, just saw that this is already a problem in OPs question

Comment: @Absurd-Mind : I don't think it does. Correct me if I am wrong. p1 is reinitialized every time a test runs.

Comment: @NewUser but board is only initialized once when the PawnTest is initialized. The same board object will be used in both tests.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind. AH.. I was completely focused on the p1 object. Did not even relaize this. Thanks.